# How to copy data between Virtual machines

Tags: virtualbox

I have a linux machine, and windows is installed as a VM. While copying a data from linux desktop into windows, data is not receiving (I mean copy and paste).

Is there any way to copy data between two virtual machines?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer should be complex, I hope not too much complicate, but more you read down more it is complex:

1. You can copy few (or more) lines with ***copy & paste*** mechanism.

   For this you need to [share clipboard between host OS and guest OS](https://superuser.com/questions/42134/virtualbox-shared-clipboard), installing **Guest Addition** on both the virtual machines (probably setting *bidirectional* and restarting them).
   You *copy* from *guest OS* in the clipboard that is shared with the *host OS*.
   Then you *paste* from the *host OS* to the second *guest OS*.
2. You can enable **drag and drop** too with the same method (Click on the machine, settings, general, advanced, drag and drop: set to *bidirectional* )
3. You can have **common** ***Shared Folders*** on both virtual machines and use one of the directory shared as buffer to copy.

   Installing **Guest Additions**
   you have the possibility to set [Shared Folders too](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders). As you put a file in a shared folder from *host OS* or from *guest OS*, is immediately visible to the other. (Keep in mind that can arise some problems for date/time of the files when there are different clock settings on the different virtual machines).
   *If you use the same folder shared on more machines you can exchange files directly copying them in this folder.*
4. You can use **usual method to copy files between 2 different computer** with client-server  application. (e.g. `scp` with `sshd` active for linux, winscp... [you can get some info about SSH servers e.g. here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_servers))

   You need an active server (`sshd`) on the receiving machine and a client on the sending machine. Of course you need to have the authorization setted (via password or, better, via an [automatic authentication method](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys)).

   **Note:** many Linux/Ubuntu distribution install `sshd` by default: you can see if it is running with `pgrep sshd` from a shell. You can install with `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`.
5. You can **mount part of the file system** of a virtual machine via [NFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) or [SSHFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) on the other, or you can **share file and directory** with Samba.
   You may find interesting the article [Sharing files between guest and host without VirtualBox shared folders](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Sharing_files_on_OSE) with detailed step by step instructions.

You should remember that you are dialling with a little network of machines with different operative systems, and in particular:

- Each virtual machine has its own operative system running on and acts as a physical machine.
- Each virtual machine is an instance of a program *owned* by an *user* in the hosting operative system and should undergo the restrictions of the *user* in the *hosting OS*.

  E.g Let we say that Hastur and Meow are users of the hosting machine, but they did not allow each other to see their directories (no read/write/execute authorization). When each of them run a virtual machine, for the hosting OS those virtual machine are two normal programs owned by Hastur and Meow and cannot see the private directory of the other user. This is a restriction due to the *hosting OS*. It's easy to overcame it: it's enough to give authorization to read/write/execute to a directory or to chose a different directory in which both users can read/write/execute.
- Windows likes mouse and Linux fingers. :-)
  I mean I suggest you to enable *Drag & drop* to be cosy with the Windows machines and the *Shared folders* or to be cosy with Linux.
  When you will need to be fast with Linux **you will feel the need** of `ssh-keygen` and to [Generate once SSH Keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) to copy files on/from a remote machine without writing password anymore. In this way it functions `bash` auto-completion remotely too!

Comment: yup....it is working... :) and the answer is looking bit complicated.

Comment: @meow ...a bit or a bit too much? :-) When you deal with different operative systems you always have to deal with the two sides of the same problem :(. The 1st, 2nd and 3rd, points are fast and almost simple. The 4th starts to be more complex, but useful in a Linux way (especially the second part). The 5-th point is more for office or specific and/or professional tasks (e.g. I want to run 2 `WWW servers` on two different virtual machine but I want to share analytic logs maybe on a third machine... so if one machine crashes or is under attack the second will be not...)

Comment: @ Hastur : while reading I got more confused, and i read again and again.. :) now it is clear.. also an interesting and very useful answer.

Comment: @meow Thanks but please help me to write in a more understandable way asking where it is not clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

You could use scp or WinSCP for this.
An alternative might be to set up shared folders between the VirtualBox and the host machine.

I don't have VirtualBox, but to copy from my host machine to it's KVM guests I use:

```
scp <filename> guest:
```

The ':' at the end is required to let scp know it's copying to "another" machine and not to the host machine. The command for a VirtualBox VM is probably the same.

I found a more detailed explanation [here](http://sandilands.info/sgordon/accessing-virtualbox-guests-using-ssh-winscp-tunnelling), but since I don't use VirtualBox myself I cannot verify it.

Comment: Actually, I was asked about copying data, but copying through file, I haven't checked that.
Like, 5 lines of data...something like that...

Comment: If you want drag-n-drop, it looks like this is not supported for security reasons: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=62815&hilit=drag+n+drop .

Answer (score 1):

Check the 'Advanced' tab of the 'General' settings of your VM in Virtual Box Manager. You can there activate the shared clipboard and the drag'n'drop.

More of it, you can set up shares between host and VM in the VM settings.

And finally, you can start a virtual network linking all VMs and optionally the host. Go to the global preferences, line Network, tab 'host-only network' and click the button add. Next,in the VM settings, add a host-only network adapter and select the private network you created.

HTH