# Failed to run devstack on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, openstack

Attempting to install DevStack on ubuntu16.04 but ended failed. How i supposed to do ? iam very new to linux. dont blame me
[Run stack failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmYUG.png)
[error.logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVBXA.png)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the **full** text directly into your question and use the [Formatting Help](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help).

Comment: can you teach me how to copy logs in virtualbox into text ?

Comment: If you can't [copy and paste](https://askubuntu.com/questions/691585/copy-paste-and-dragdrop-not-working-in-vmware-machine-with-ubuntu). For more extensive [data movment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/508463/how-to-copy-data-between-virtual-machines). Or you could post the files on [pastebin](pastebin.com) from the vm.

Comment: iam not familiar with ubuntu server running virtualbox , iam confused to copy paste the text. so i just can screenshoot